# How to Automate RESTful services Functional Testing using SOAP UI with relevance to environment?

Tags: rest, soapui, restful-authentication

I have to automate functional testing of a series of RESTful services using SOAP UI, such the one single script should be able to do the testing in different environments.

So, it is like, I should be able pass endpoint url, header parameters and request bodys parameters dynamically basing on the environment in which the script is being loaded.

Note: I have my systems configured for different environments. Say it is "Env=e1" development environment.

Kindly, suggest me if there is also another tool, that can perform such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI can handle different environments out of the box.

If you have the non-Pro version, then you can just parametrize the endpoint. This is described in the [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties.html#4-Example----Centralized-Endpoint).

If you have the Pro version, then you can define all your environment on the Environments tab. This is also described in the [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/soapui-projects/environment-handling.html#3-Working-with-Environments).